# Java - Get var information from another JDialog

Tags: java, swing, get, textfield, jdialog

I've got a JDialog with a textField and a button. If I press the button and the textField is empty, it prints an error message. But now I want to open a new Window (JDialog I guess) with the information of the textField.

```
{
    JButton aceptarButton = new JButton("Aceptar");
    aceptarButton.setBounds(332, 387, 86, 23);
    contentPanel.add(aceptarButton);
    aceptarButton.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 11));

    aceptarButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
        ArticuloDAO dao = new ArticuloDAO();
            Articulo a = new Articulo();

            if (nombreField.getText().equals("")) {
                System.out.println("Nombre");
            }else{
                String nombre = nombreField.getText();
                a.setNombre(nombre);
                dao.insert(a);
                Success s = new Success();
                s.setVisible(true);
                setVisible(false);
            }
        }

    });

    aceptarButton.setActionCommand("OK");
    getRootPane().setDefaultButton(aceptarButton);
}
```

A new window saying "Name is missing" should open whenever I click OK and the textField nombreField is empty. How is it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply use `JOptionPane` for this. Just call it like so:

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Name is missing");
```

It will display the message in a dialog box and wait for OK.

Answer (score 0):

To show a popup messages from any kind you can use the class JOptionPane and their static methods. in your case `JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Name is missing");` should do the thing.